# how do I create a subfolder with the Music folder, please?

Tags: directory

I am 70 years old and brand new to Ubuntu. The only OS I have experience with is Windows 7.

I want to create subfolders within the Music folder to hold MP3s and PDFs. Please, how do I do this?

Because of my age and lack of knowledge about Ubuntu 16.04, please give a clear and detailed answer.

Thank you very much.

TomD

Answer (score 3):

Open `nautilus`, this is the usual GUI `file manager` shipped with Ubuntu. There navigate into your `music folder` and right click into the empty area.
There will a drop down menu pop up where you can choose to create a `new folder`, press that choose your name for that new folder and you're done. Do this as often as needed. This way when clicking on a file/folder symbol you as well get multiple options for that your selection.

Comment: Please, how do I open nautilus? As I said, I am brand new to Ubuntu and know nothing about the OS. Thank you very much. TomD

Comment: This is if you not changed it, the icon just below the ubuntu icon in the left side launcher bar. In other words the seconf from the top. Tell me if this is not the case :)

Comment: @tomd You can find an icon for the file browser `Nautilus` the way Videonauth described.  You can also find programs by name by clicking on the Launch Button on the side bar.  Then type in the name of the application you want.  In this case, type in `nautilus`.  Usually the icon for the application you are looking for will appear within three characters.  Doing this will help you to recognize the icon of the program you're looking for, which you will find where Videonauth described.